# Stability of VAR$(p)$: Prove $\det(I_{Kp}-\tilde{A}z)=\det(I_k-A_1z-\ldots-A_pz^p)$

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, determinant

Given we have a VAR$(p)$ process written in the companion form
$$\tilde{y}=\tilde{v}+\tilde{A}\tilde{y}_{t-1}+\tilde{u}_t$$
where 
$$\tilde{A}=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
 A_1& A_2 & \ldots & A_{p-1} & A_p \\ 
 I_k& 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0& I_k &  & 0 &0  \\ 
 \vdots&  &\ddots  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 0&  0&\ldots  & I_k & 0
\end{array} \right).$$
(I follow the notation from [Lütkepohl, New Introduction to Multivariate Time Series](https://books.google.at/books?hl=de&lr=&id=COUFCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR4&dq=new%20introduction%20to%20multivariate%20time%20series&ots=wE4GfrWIHs&sig=sh8tNMAuD1dwz2g-sPyNg5Fhrtw#v=onepage&q=new%20introduction%20to%20multivariate%20time%20series&f=false))

Exercise 2.1 (p. 67) asks to show $\det(I_{Kp}-\tilde{A}z)=\det(I_k-A_1z-\ldots-A_pz^p)$ in order to use the common test for stability of the process. However, it seems like I do not have sufficient knowledge in theory regarding determinants of block matrices. I really do not know how to solve
$$\det\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
 I_k-A_1z& -A_2z & \ldots & -A_{p-1}z & -A_pz \\ 
 -I_kz& I_k & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0& -I_kz &  & 0 &0  \\ 
 \vdots&  &\ddots  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 0&  0&\ldots  & -I_kz & I_k
\end{array} \right).$$
I have a couple of properties for matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc}A&B\\C&D\end{array} \right)$ but I do not see how this helps me to get to the solution. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Generalizing Proposition 1.1 in Hamilton's book to the matrix case should do the trick.

Comment: Great, thank you @ChristophHanck! This was the perfect reference for me. Could you transfer your comment into an answer such that I accept it?

Comment: Thanks, but mere references do not meet the standards for an answer on CV, as far as I understand!